# creating and validating a database field that can take an array or two different objects

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a db field that takes an array of two different objects, the array should either be a key in two other tables:

```
    x_id = Column(ARRAY(ForeignKey("z.id")), nullable=False, index=True)
```

The `x_id` field can either be a foreign key from either of the table `y` or table `z`. Table `z` has a foreign key reference to `y`

I want to  be  able  to  validate that the  foreign key exists in  either  table  'y'  or  'z' in  my

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. You are not completely clear. Is it required that a ForeignKey is supplied? Can they also be both (y and z) added?

Comment: I think that this is not possible using SQL constraints. Neither arrays of foreign keys are supported (yet), nor "generic foreign keys", though the latter [can be implemented to some extent](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/generic_associations/generic_fk.html) in your application.